# Counting percentage of element occurence from an attribute in a class. Python

Tags: python, count, counting

I have a class called transaction that have these attributes

```
Transaction([time_stamp, time_of_day, day_of_month ,week_day, duration, amount, trans_type,
location])
```

an example of the data set is as such

```
timestamp   time    date    weekday duration    amount  trans_type      location
1           0:07    3       thu      2                  balance         driveup
2           0:07    3       thu      6          20      withdrawal      campus a
3           0:20    1       tue      2          357     advance         driveup
4           0:26    3       thu      2          20      withdrawal      campus b
5           0:26    4       fri      2          35       deposit            driveup
```

There are different transaction types. define in trans_type which are:

```
advance, balance, deposit, transfer, withdrawal
```

How do I calculate the percentage types of transaction?

For example, this will be the resulting list:

```
[('advance', 20), ('balance', 20), ('deposit', 20), ('transfer', 0), ('withdrawal', 40)]
```

This is what i have tried:

```
#percentage of the different types of transactions
advance = 0
balance = 0
deposit = 0
transfer = 0
withdrawal = 0
for element in range(len(atm_transaction_list)):
    for trans_type in element:
        if trans_type == 'advance':
            advance += 1
        elif trans_type == 'balance':
            balance += 1
        elif trans_type == 'deposit':
            deposit += 1
        elif trans_type == 'transfer':
            transfer += 1
        elif trans_type == 'withdrawal':
            withdrawal += 1
```

Comment: thats what i have tried. i put my code in just then

Comment: so im trying to count all the different occurence for each transaction types first then calculate the percentage later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `for element in range(len(atm_transaction_list)):`, you are iterating over integers in a range. This is generally used when you want to work with indices. However, you're not doing that. Simply iterate over the transaction list itself, with `for transaction in atm_transaction_list:`. Each `transaction` will then be a `Transaction` object.

I would also recommend storing your results in a dictionary instead of in five separate references. You can then add to a key's value whenever it's seen.

```
result = {'advance':0, 'balance':0, 'deposit':0, 'transfer':0, 'withdrawal':0}
for element in atm_transaction_list:
    result[element.trans_type] += 1
```

This will give you a dictionary that you can access with something like `result['advance']` to see the number of `'advance'` transactions.

Now divide each key's value by the total number of transactions and multiply by 100 to get the percentage:

```
l = len(atm_transaction_list)
for key in result:
    result[key] = result[key] / l * 100
```

Comment: Hi, atm_transaction_list is ([time_stamp, time_of_day, day_of_month ,week_day, duration, amount, trans_type,
    location])

Comment: Hi i have revised my code as you said. you can check. but it says typeError 'int' object not iterable from "for trans_type in element:"

Comment: And that's why `for trans_type in element` didn't make it into my answer. Also, please don't add code from answers into your question's code, as this makes it difficult to see what the question was and how the answers solve it.

Comment: Ohh sorry. So you mean dont put "for trans_type in element"?

Comment: That's right: don't do that. If you're still unclear on why any piece of code is or is not being used, you might need to revisit some instructional materials.

Comment: Ohh i see. So keep the if and elif's?

Comment: You can throw away everything after "This is what I have tried:" in your question. Replace it with the contents of this answer's code blocks.

Comment: when i try to sort the dictionary according to their keys. only the keys got printed from this print(sorted(result)). how do i make so that the corresponding values also print out?

Comment: @Kutam - Use `print(sorted(result.items()))` instead.

Comment: ohh i see, how do i make it so if the values is 0, it doesnt show up?

Comment: @Kutam - Filter it so that only the items with a non-zero value remain: `print(sorted(item for item in result.items() if item[1]))`.

Comment: @Kutam - Or you can instead just initialize an empty dictionary with `result = {}`.