# counting number of transactions of different types per location. python

Tags: python, count, transactions, counting

I have a class called transactions with the following attributes.

```
transactions([time, date ,weekday, duration, amount, type, location])
```

this is the sample data types

```
time    date    weekday duration    amount  type       location
0:07    3       thu      2                  balance    driveup
0:07    3       thu      6          20      withdrawal campusA
0:20    1       tue      2          357     deposit    campusB
```

the type of transactions are

```
balance, withdrawal, deposit, advance, transfer
```

i have to count the number of different types of transaction in different location
which will result in something like this

```
Location | Advance | Balance | Deposit | Transfer | Withdrawal | Total
'driveup'|     4   |     191 |    247  |       28 |        530  |  1000 
'campus' |     1   |      2  |    3    |     4    |      5      |  15
```

the result should emit a list, something like this:

```
 [['Location', 'Advance', 'Balance', 'Deposit', 'Transfer', 'Withdrawal', 'Total'],  
['driveup', 4, 191, 247, 28, 530, 1000],['campus', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 15]]
```

note: the example table and the resulting list only shows 2 location. there are 3 different locations. 'driveup', 'campusa', 'campusb'

how do i make the list?

i tried something like this, but i think its very unefficient and a more concise code is available, any ideas?

```
   amtrlo = lust(zip(amounts, transactions, locations))
for element in amtrlo:
    a = element[1]
    b = element[2]
    c = element[0]
    if a == 'advance' and b == 'driveup':
        driveup_advance.append((a,b,c))
    elif a == 'balance' and b == 'driveup':
        driveup_balance.append((a,b,c))
    elif a == 'transfer' and b == 'driveup':
        driveup_transfer.append((a,b,c))
    elif a == 'withdrawal' and b == 'driveup':
        driveup_withdrawal.append((a,b,c))
    elif a == 'deposit' and b == 'driveup':
        driveup_deposit.append((a,b,c))
    if a == 'advance' and b == 'campusa':
        driveup_advance.append((a,b,c))
    elif a == 'balance' and b == 'campusa':
        driveup_balance.append((a,b,c))
    elif a == 'transfer' and b == 'campusa':
        driveup_transfer.append((a,b,c))
    elif a == 'withdrawal' and b == 'campusa':
        driveup_withdrawal.append((a,b,c))
    elif a == 'deposit' and b == 'campusa':
        driveup_deposit.append((a,b,c))
    if a == 'advance' and b == 'campusb':
        driveup_advance.append((a,b,c))
    elif a == 'balance' and b == 'campusb':
        driveup_balance.append((a,b,c))
    elif a == 'transfer' and b == 'campusb':
        driveup_transfer.append((a,b,c))
    elif a == 'withdrawal' and b == 'campusb':
        driveup_withdrawal.append((a,b,c))
    elif a == 'deposit' and b == 'campusb':
        driveup_deposit.append((a,b,c))
```

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 can you help me with this?

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33213843/counting-percentage-of-element-occurence-from-an-attribute-in-a-class-python)?

Comment: haha yes correct @TigerhawkT3 this was from the transactions homework i asked you yesterday or 2 days ago

Comment: thats the code i have put up @TigerhawkT3

Answer (score 1):

This is done in a similar manner to my [other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33214433/2617068). Start a dictionary, then loop over your transaction list and create a nested dictionary with pre-initialized values for locations not yet in the result list.

```
class Transaction:
    def __init__(self, time, date ,weekday, duration, amount, _type, location):
            self.time = time
            self.date = date
            self.weekday = weekday
            self.duration = duration
            self.amount = amount
            self.type = _type
            self.location = location

atm_transaction_list = [Transaction(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'balance', 'driveup'),
                        Transaction(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'withdrawal', 'driveup'),
                        Transaction(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'deposit', 'driveup'),
                        Transaction(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'advance', 'driveup'),
                        Transaction(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'advance', 'driveup'),
                        Transaction(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'transfer', 'driveup'),
                        Transaction(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'transfer', 'driveup'),
                        Transaction(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'withdrawal', 'campus'),
                        Transaction(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'deposit', 'campus'),
                        Transaction(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'advance', 'campus'),
                        Transaction(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'advance', 'campus'),
                        Transaction(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'advance', 'campus'),
                        Transaction(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'advance', 'campus'),
                        Transaction(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'transfer', 'campus'),
                        Transaction(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'transfer', 'campus'),
                        Transaction(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'transfer', 'campus')]

result = {}
for element in atm_transaction_list:
    if element.location not in result:
        result[element.location] = {'advance':0, 'balance':0, 'deposit':0, 'withdrawal':0, 'transfer':0, 'total':0}
    result[element.location][element.type] += 1
```

With the following result:

```
>>> result
{'driveup': {'deposit': 1, 'balance': 1, 'advance': 2, 'transfer': 2, 'total': 0, 'withdrawal': 1}, 'campus': {'deposit': 1, 'balance': 0, 'advance': 4, 'transfer': 3, 'total': 0, 'withdrawal': 1}}
```

Which you can tidily display:

```
print('Location   | Advance    |  Balance   |  Deposit   |  Transfer  | Withdrawal |  Total')
for key in result:
    print('{:<10} | {advance:^10} | {balance:^10} | {deposit:^10} | {transfer:^10} | {withdrawal:^10} | {total:^10}'.format(**result[key]))
```

Result:

```
Location   | Advance    |  Balance   |  Deposit   |  Transfer  | Withdrawal |  Total
driveup    |     2      |     1      |     1      |     2      |     1      |     0
campus     |     4      |     0      |     1      |     3      |     1      |     0
```

Comment: thanks, the result should in this form actually, the table is just for easy viewing purposes. [['Location', 'Advance', 'Balance', 'Deposit', 'Transfer', 'Withdrawal', 'Total'],  
['driveup', 4, 191, 247, 28, 530, 1000],['campus', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 15]]

Comment: also i have to sort it. so the values is like  ['driveup', 4, 191, 247, 28, 530, 1000] which corresponds to each type of transactions

Comment: @Gusto - You can certainly do a simple `sorted(result['driveup'], key=result['driveup'].get)`, but if you wanted to print them all in a nice table, each row would need its own header.

Comment: ahh yea. but my tutor said the resulting list should like this `[['Location', 'Advance', 'Balance', 'Deposit', 'Transfer', 'Withdrawal', 'Total'],
  ['campusa', 0, 5, 0, 0, 42, 47], ['campusb', 3, 77, 56, 8, 219, 363], ['driveup', 1, 62, 73, 6, 148, 290]]`

Comment: Your tutor told you to make `list`s out of differentiated data?

Comment: ill show you the instructions. This is a list that contains lists. The first of these lists contains the string 'Location' followed by the names of the different types of transactions (sorted alphabetically), followed by the string 'Total'. 
Each of the following lists contains the name of the location (a string), followed by the number of transactions of the given type at that location (integer), followed by the total number of transactions at that location (integer). 
The location names (and thus their corresponding lists of values) must be sorted alphabetically."

Comment: an example of the resulting list is as such `[['Location', 'Advance', 'Balance', 'Deposit', 'Transfer', 'Withdrawal', 'Total'],
  ['campusa', 0, 5, 0, 0, 42, 47], ['campusb', 3, 77, 56, 8, 219, 363], ['driveup', 1, 62, 73, 6, 148, 290]]`

Comment: like your code emits the correct values. but not in the format the homerwork ask

Comment: You could do `new_result = [[key]+sorted(result[key].values()) for key in result]`. I mean, I don't know why you'd want such a suboptimal data structure, but you could do it.

Comment: yea me too, i find your result is much easier to understand aswell

Comment: and then append it to   ` [['Location', 'Advance', 'Balance', 'Deposit', 'Transfer', 'Withdrawal', 'Total']]` ?  so that the result would be like this  `[['Location', 'Advance', 'Balance', 'Deposit', 'Transfer', 'Withdrawal', 'Total'], ['campusa', 0, 5, 0, 0, 42, 47], ['campusb', 3, 77, 56, 8, 219, 363], ['driveup', 1, 62, 73, 6, 148, 290]]'

Comment: @Gusto - Wait, you need to sort each row by value, but it also has to correspond to a predetermined header?

Comment: not sort it by value, but sort it by the predetermined header @TigerhawkT3

Comment: the code you gave is correct. so i did this `new_result = [[key]+sorted(result[key].values()) for key in result].

    the_list = [['Location', 'Advance', 'Balance', 'Deposit', 'Transfer', 'Withdrawal', 'Total'], new_result]` but the_list is in a list within a list, how do i extract it, so just the elements. because right now this is the result `[['Location', 'Advance', 'Balance', 'Deposit', 'Transfer', 'Withdrawal', 'Total'], [['driveup', 4, 28, 191, 247, 530, 1000]]]`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dictionary with keys location_transtype to capture the counts.  Then you wouldn't have to write out each MxN condition.  You just have to figure out how to reinterpret that into your output table.

Comment: what do you mean? so put location and trans_type together?

Comment: Yes.  As a key, so for every row, grab those two, and look it up in your dictionary.  If you found it, increment it.  Otherwise make a new value = 1.

Comment: ahh okk, i know what you mean, but im not quite sure how to initialize the dictionary. how would you put it?

Comment: initially the dictionary would be empty.  Then you add entries as you scan the transactions.